# Reading data from database, saving to new list and adding list to grid

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I made some changes to how I was saving the data in order for it to show up on a kendo grid. Right now my giant method is getting data from the database (using `getValue`), then creating a new list to save both data onto the single list to populate the kendo grid with one list even though they are two different types of data (although similar).

Here is my current code that works:

```
//Grabs the value of angles and points already existing in db and returns the data to the view 
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult ReadMeasurements([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string viewType)
{
    try
    {
        JsonResult json = new JsonResult();
        List<AngleData> angledata = UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.Planning, ScreenName.Planning.ToString() + "Angles" + viewType, UserSessionMode.Database) as List<AngleData> ?? new List<AngleData>();
        List<PointData> pointData = UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.Planning, ScreenName.Planning.ToString() + "Points" + viewType, UserSessionMode.Database) as List<PointData> ?? new List<PointData>();
        List<PlanningViewParam> measurements = new List<PlanningViewParam>();

        if (pointData.Count() != 0 && angledata.Count() != 0)
        {
            foreach (AngleData i in angledata)
            {
                string col = "#" + ColorTranslator.FromHtml(String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", (int)(i.color.r * 255), (int)(i.color.g * 255), (int)(i.color.b * 255))).Name.Remove(0, 2);
                int angleVal = (int)i.angleValue;
                measurements.Add(new PlanningViewParam()
                {
                    Color = col,
                    Label = "Angle",
                    Value = angleVal,
                    Number = i.angleNumber,
                    AngleName = i.name
                });
            }

            var numbers = new HashSet<int>();
            var distinctPoints = pointData.Where(x => numbers.Add(x.pointNumber));

            foreach (PointData f in distinctPoints)
            {
                string col = "#" + ColorTranslator.FromHtml(String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", (int)(f.color.r * 255), (int)(f.color.g * 255), (int)(f.color.b * 255))).Name.Remove(0, 2);
                string angleValWithQ = f.pointAnglesValue;
                string pointAnglesVal = "";
                if (angleValWithQ != null)
                {
                    pointAnglesVal = angleValWithQ.Replace("?", "°");
                }
                string pointNam = f.pointUniqueKey;
                measurements.Add(new PlanningViewParam()
                {
                    PointColor = col,
                    PointLabel = "Point",
                    PointValue = pointAnglesVal,
                    PointName = pointNam,
                    Number = f.pointNumber
                });
            }
            return json = Json(measurements.ToDataSourceResult(request, i => new PlanningViewParam()
            {

                Color = i.Color,
                Label = i.Label,
                Value = i.Value,
                PointColor = i.PointColor,
                PointLabel = i.PointLabel,
                PointValue = i.PointValue,
                PointName = i.PointName,
                AngleName = i.AngleName,
                Number = i.Number
            }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        else if (angledata.Count() != 0)
        {
            foreach (AngleData i in angledata)
            {
                string col = "#" + ColorTranslator.FromHtml(String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", (int)(i.color.r * 255), (int)(i.color.g * 255), (int)(i.color.b * 255))).Name.Remove(0, 2);
                int angleVal = (int)i.angleValue;
                measurements.Add(new PlanningViewParam()
                {
                    Color = col,
                    Label = "Angle",
                    Value = angleVal,
                    Number = i.angleNumber,
                    AngleName = i.name
                });
            }
            return json = Json(measurements.ToDataSourceResult(request, i => new PlanningViewParam()
            {
                Color = i.Color,
                Label = i.Label,
                Value = i.Value,
                Number = i.Number,
                AngleName = i.AngleName
            }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        else if (pointData.Count() != 0)
        {
            var numbers = new HashSet<int>();
            var distinctPoints = pointData.Where(x => numbers.Add(x.pointNumber));
            foreach (PointData f in distinctPoints)
            {
                string col = "#" + ColorTranslator.FromHtml(String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", (int)(f.color.r * 255), (int)(f.color.g * 255), (int)(f.color.b * 255))).Name.Remove(0, 2);
                string angleValWithQ = f.pointAnglesValue;
                string pointAnglesVal = "";
                if (angleValWithQ != null)
                {
                    pointAnglesVal = angleValWithQ.Replace("?", "°");
                }
                int pointNumber = f.pointNumber;
                string pointNam = f.pointUniqueKey;
                measurements.Add(new PlanningViewParam()
                {
                    PointColor = col,
                    PointLabel = "Point",
                    PointValue = pointAnglesVal,
                    PointName = pointNam,
                    Number = pointNumber
                });
            }
            return json = Json(measurements.ToDataSourceResult(request, f => new PlanningViewParam()
            {
                PointColor = f.PointColor,
                PointLabel = f.PointLabel,
                PointValue = f.PointValue,
                PointName = f.PointName,
                Number = f.Number
            }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Item(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

`AngleData` has `Color` color property which is described as:

```
public partial class Color
{
    public float b;

    public float a;

    public float r;

    public float g;
}
```

So, basically, this method works perfectly but I want to simplify it and I'm not sure how. Currently the performance of this method is ~1.05s!

ToDataSourceResult Extension methods:

```
    public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult(this DataTable dataTable, DataSourceRequest request);
    public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult(this IEnumerable enumerable, DataSourceRequest request);
    public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult(this IQueryable enumerable, DataSourceRequest request);
    public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult<TModel, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TModel> enumerable, DataSourceRequest request, Func<TModel, TResult> selector);
    public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult(this IEnumerable enumerable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState);
    public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult<TModel, TResult>(this IQueryable<TModel> enumerable, DataSourceRequest request, Func<TModel, TResult> selector);
    public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult(this IQueryable queryable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState);
    public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult<TModel, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TModel> enumerable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState, Func<TModel, TResult> selector);
    public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult<TModel, TResult>(this IQueryable<TModel> enumerable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState, Func<TModel, TResult> selector);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Distinct values of a `list / IEnumerable<T>`**

Also it is a valid appoach to use

> ```
> var numbers = new HashSet<int>();
> var distinctPoints = pointData.Where(x => numbers.Add(x.pointNumber));
> ```

to get distinct `PointData` of a `List<PointData>` you should consider to do this right by adding a specialized [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which only checks equality based on the `pointNumber` property/field.

This `IEqualityComparer<PointData>`, if you don't need it somewhere else too, could just be a private class like

```
private class SpecializedPointDataComparer : IEqualityComparer<PointData>
{
    public bool Equals(PointData x, PointData y)
    {
        // your implementation here
    }

    public int GetHashCode(PointData obj)
    {
        // your implementation here
    }
}
```

For proper implementation of the `GetHashCode()` method you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/2655508 .

and can then be used like

```
foreach (PointData f in pointData.Distinct(new SpecializedPointDataComparer())
{
    .......
}
```

---

Unfortunately you didn't provide neither the `AngleData` nor the `PointData` class. Therefor this is just guessing:

This line

> ```
> string col = "#" + ColorTranslator.FromHtml(String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", (int)(f.color.r * 255), (int)(f.color.g * 255), (int)(f.color.b * 255))).Name.Remove(0, 2);
> ```

could be simplified, **if** `f.color` is a `System.Drawing.Color`, by using

```
string color = String.Format("#{0}", f.color.Name.Remove(0,2).ToUpper());
```

and this should be extracted to a method like

```
private string GetColorAsText(Color color)
{
    return String.Format("#{0}", color.Name.Remove(0,2).ToUpper());
}
```

to reduce code duplication which leads us to the next point....

**Code duplication**

You should always follow the `DRY` principle, which means **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself which boils down to **reduce code duplication**  if possible by extracting duplicated code to methods.
This has the advantage of smaller methods which are easier to read and maintain. **Bob the Maintainer** will thank you for following this.

So, what parts are duplicated ?

- the loop over the `List<AngleData>`
- the loop over the `List<PointData>`

So let us add a method for each loop.

```
private IEnumerable<PlanningViewParam> GetPlanningViewParameters(IEnumerable<AngleData> angleData)
{
    foreach (AngleData aData in angleData)
    {
        yield return new PlanningViewParam()
        {
            Color = GetColorAsText(aData.color),
            Label = "Angle",
            Value = (int)aData.angleValue;,
            Number = aData.angleNumber,
            AngleName = aData.name
        };
    }
}
```

and

```
private IEnumerable<PlanningViewParam> GetPlanningViewParameters(IEnumerable<PointData> pointData)
{
    foreach (PointData pData in pointData)
    {
        yield return new PlanningViewParam()
        {
            PointColor = GetColorAsText(pData.color),
            PointLabel = "Point",
            PointValue = (pData.pointAnglesValue != null) ? pData.pointAnglesValue.Replace("?", "°") : string.Empty,
            PointName = pData.pointUniqueKey,
            Number = pData.pointNumber
        };
    }
}
```

this would reduce the `if..else if` statements of your former method like

```
if (pointData.Count() != 0 && angledata.Count() != 0)
{

    measurements.AddRange(GetPlanningViewParameters(angledata));

    var distinctPoints = pointData.Distinct(new SpecializedPointDataComparer());

    measurements.AddRange(GetPlanningViewParameters(distinctPoints));

    return json = Json(measurements.ToDataSourceResult(request, i => new PlanningViewParam()
    {

        Color = i.Color,
        Label = i.Label,
        Value = i.Value,
        PointColor = i.PointColor,
        PointLabel = i.PointLabel,
        PointValue = i.PointValue,
        PointName = i.PointName,
        AngleName = i.AngleName,
        Number = i.Number
    }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

else if (angledata.Count() != 0)
{
    measurements.AddRange(GetPlanningViewParameters(angledata));

    return json = Json(measurements.ToDataSourceResult(request, i => new PlanningViewParam()
    {
        Color = i.Color,
        Label = i.Label,
        Value = i.Value,
        Number = i.Number,
        AngleName = i.AngleName
    }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
else if (pointData.Count() != 0)
{
    var distinctPoints = pointData.Distinct(new SpecializedPointDataComparer());

    measurements.AddRange(GetPlanningViewParameters(distinctPoints));

    return json = Json(measurements.ToDataSourceResult(request, f => new PlanningViewParam()
    {
        PointColor = f.PointColor,
        PointLabel = f.PointLabel,
        PointValue = f.PointValue,
        PointName = f.PointName,
        Number = f.Number
    }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

We now see, that the `if..else if` statements just decide what should be returned but are doing almost the same things.

- If we think about this, we can reduce the small code duplication by filling the `List<PlanningViewParam>` outside of the `if.. else if` construct.
- We can also ommit the last `else if` because it is redundant. This is because if one of the first conditions is met the method returns a value and therefor this won't be reached anymore.
- The line `JsonResult json = new JsonResult();` is not needed at all. You can simply return `Json(...)`.
- There is no need to use the `Count()` method on a `List<T>` because a `List<T>`has a property `Count` which should be used. If you plan to use this method with `IEnumerable<PointData>` and `IEnumerable<AngleData>` then you shouldn't use the `Count()` method either if you only want to know if there are any data in the `IEnumerable<T>`. By calling `Count()` on an `IEnumerable<T>` will iterate over all elements, if the underlaying type isn't a kind of collection.
  By using the `Any()` method the iteration will stop after the first occurance of an valid item.

Taking all this would then lead to

```
//Grabs the value of angles and points already existing in db and returns the data to the view 
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult ReadMeasurements([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string viewType)
{
    try
    {
        List<AngleData> angledata = UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.Planning, ScreenName.Planning.ToString() + "Angles" + viewType, UserSessionMode.Database) as List<AngleData> ?? new List<AngleData>();
        List<PointData> pointData = UserSession.GetValue(StateNameEnum.Planning, ScreenName.Planning.ToString() + "Points" + viewType, UserSessionMode.Database) as List<PointData> ?? new List<PointData>();
        List<PlanningViewParam> measurements = new List<PlanningViewParam>();

        measurements.AddRange(GetPlanningViewParameters(angledata));

        var distinctPoints = pointData.Distinct(new SpecializedPointDataComparer());

        measurements.AddRange(GetPlanningViewParameters(distinctPoints));

        if (pointData.Any() && angledata.Any())
        {
            return Json(measurements.ToDataSourceResult(request, m => new PlanningViewParam()
            {

                Color = i.Color,
                Label = i.Label,
                Value = m.Value,
                PointColor = m.PointColor,
                PointLabel = m.PointLabel,
                PointValue = m.PointValue,
                PointName = m.PointName,
                AngleName = m.AngleName,
                Number = m.Number
            }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        else if (angledata.Any())
        {

            return Json(measurements.ToDataSourceResult(request, m => new PlanningViewParam()
            {
                Color = m.Color,
                Label = m.Label,
                Value = m.Value,
                Number = m.Number,
                AngleName = m.AngleName
            }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        return Json(measurements.ToDataSourceResult(request, m => new PlanningViewParam()
        {
            PointColor = m.PointColor,
            PointLabel = m.PointLabel,
            PointValue = m.PointValue,
            PointName = m.PointName,
            Number = m.Number
        }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Item(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Because this method is `public` you should add proper xml documentation. By doing so the documentation will be seen in intellisense too.

Just hit 3 times `/` above the method and the IDE will provide the correct structure.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm still looking through your suggestions but what do you mean by, "PointValue = (pData.pointAnglesValue != null) ? pData.pointAnglesValue.Replace("?", "°"), string.Empty,"? I get an error for string.empty part.

Comment: Sorry, the comma before `string.Empty` should have been a `:` . Updated answer

Comment: Thank you. Btw, what is f in this context, " return String.Format("#{0}", f.color.Name.Remove(0,2).ToUpper()); }"? That is f.color... what is f?

Comment: A copy & paste error ;-) Updated

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will update my post but I am using Color that is r,g,b,a... so it does not contain def for name

Comment: Btw, I tried your solution almost to the tie (didn't do the hashcode proper implementation yet) and it works out nicely. The code also looks cleaner/easier to read. The only problem is the performance has not changed, it is still 1.05ms for my second viewType. My first viewType has a perf. of ~50ms. I'm not sure what could be causing it? Could be the roundtrip calls I'm making?

Comment: Is `ToDataSourceResult()` a extension method ? If yes, could you add it to the question ?

Comment: This is a builtin extension method: public static DataSourceResult ToDataSourceResult<TModel, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TModel> enumerable, DataSourceRequest request, Func<TModel, TResult> selector); I can add it to the question as well

Comment: By profiling the method in question you can identify the bottleneck.

Comment: What's the best way I can profile it? Thank you. I used firebug profiler and it just tells me the methods that are slow.

Comment: I guess firebug works on the javascript side only. You should profile this using some c# / .NET profiler so you can see if the problem is in your c# code.

Answer (score -3):

By no means am I an expert.

Personally I would break it down into a few more distinct methods.

I find it easier to follow and maintain. rather than this morass of coding. 6 months later when you come back you might be like: wtf is this?

Comment: I'm not sure this quite qualifies as an answer. It's answer-ish, but reads more like a comment.